# What's the advantage of using searchdisplaycontroller as opposed to just regular uisearchbar with separate tableview controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar, searchdisplaycontroller

What's the point? Why do apple build searchDisplayController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the `tableView` on your own you have to show and hide it by yourself. I don't think there is many more advantages by using the `searchDisplayController`.